# What is the difference between new Double(someString) and Double.parseDouble(someString)

Tags: java, floating-point, double

As far as I can tell `new Double(someString)` and `Double.parseDouble(someString)` give me the exact same result.  Is there any reason I would want to use one over the other?

Comment: @DOK Is the `parseDouble` you are talking about different than the `parseDouble` I mentioned in my question?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One returns `Double`; the other, `double`.

The differences between primitive Java types and their wrapper counterparts are discussed, for example, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html).

Comment: Ahh, I see that now looking at the Java doc... `parseDouble` returns a primative (lowercase "d") where `new` creates an object (capital "D").  Thanks :)

Comment: Also, `Double.valueOf(string)` is generally preferable to `new Double(String)`, since it caches some common values and doesn't have to create a new object every time.