# Java Inheritance Demonstration - on user input and incompatible types

Tags: java, inheritance, value-of

I'm almost done with a Java program but I'm having a snag compiling.
This program is a demonstration on inheritance, with 4 classes (including a driver) but I'm getting 4 errors on the aforementioned driver. I also have a problem with making the program general (as to allow user input) as the data I'm trying to read in are of different types. I think I need to use valueOf somewhere, but we haven't gotten that far in my class. I apologize for the length.

Here are the specifications:

*Define a class named 
Payment 
that
contains an instance variable of type 
double 
that stores the 
amount of the payment and appropriate accessor and mutator methods.
  Also create a method 
named 
paymentDetails
that outputs an English sentence to describe the amount of the payment.
Next, defi
ne a class named 
CashPayment
that is derived from 
Payment.*

*This class should 
redefine the 
paymentDetails 
method to indicate that the payment is in cash.  Include appropriate 
constructor(s).
Define a class named 
CreditCardPayment
that is derived from
Payment
.
  This class should 
contain instance variables for the name on the card, expiration date, and credit card number.*

*Include appropriate constructor(s).  Finally, redefine the 
paymentDetails
method to include all 
credit card information in the printout.
Create main method that creates at least two 
CashPayment
and two 
CreditCardPayment
objects with different values and calls 
paymentDetails
for each.
Be sure to make the program general so that a user can enter data!!!*

Here is one of the error messages:

> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\ghp3driver.java:21: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Payment

**and here is the code...**

```
 import java.util.*; //new file/class

 class ghp3driver {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
         Payment cash1 = user_input.next();
         Payment cash2 = user_input.next();
         Payment credit1 =
             user_input.next();
         Payment credit2 =
             user_input.next();
         System.out.println("Cash 1 details:");
         cash1.paymentDetails();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Cash 2 details:");
         cash2.paymentDetails();
         System.out.println();

         System.out.println("Credit 1 details:");
         credit1.paymentDetails();
         System.out.println();
         System.out.println("Credit 2 details:");
         credit2.paymentDetails();
         System.out.println();
     }
 }

 import java.util.*; //NEW FILE/CLASS

 public class Payment {
     private double amount;
     public Payment() { //constructor
         amount = 0.0;
     }

     public Payment(double paymentAmount) { //initializes payment amount
         amount = paymentAmount;
     }

     public void setPayment(double paymentAmount) {
         amount = paymentAmount;
     }

     public double getPayment() {
         return amount;
     }

     public void paymentDetails() {
         System.out.println("The payment amount is " + amount);
     }

 }
 class CreditCardPayment extends Payment {
     private String date, name, ccn;

     public CreditCardPayment(double amount, String date, String name, String ccn) {
         super(amount);
         this.date = date;
         this.name = name;
         this.ccn = ccn;
     }

     public void paymentDetails() { //printing
         System.out.println("Name on card: " + this.getName());
         System.out.println("Expiration date: " + this.getDate());
         System.out.println("Credit card number: " + this.getCcn());
         System.out.println("The payment by credit card amount is " + getPayment());

     }

     public String getCcn() {
         return ccn;
     }

     public void setCcn(String ccn) {
         this.ccn = ccn;
     }

     public String getDate() {
         return date;
     }

     public void setDate(String date) {
         this.date = date;
     }

     public String getName() {
         return name;
     }

     public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
     }
 }

 class CashPayment extends Payment {

     public CashPayment(double paymentAmount) {
         super(paymentAmount);
     }

     public void paymentDetails() {
         System.out.println("The payment cash amount is " + this.getPayment());
     }
 }
```

Comment: What do you think _String cannot be converted to Payment_ means?

Comment: What do you think _Payment cash1 = user_input.next( );_ should do? Why do you think so?

Comment: Well,  the user input String cannot be converted to Payment (a double), and I'm trying to find a way around that. As for  Payment cash1 = user_input.next(): that's assigning the input from the keyboard to cash1, a value to be displayed for later.

Comment: You need to use generate different Type through constructor

Answer (score 0):

Your statements

```
Payment cash1 = user_input.next( );
Payment cash2 = user_input.next( );
Payment credit1 =
user_input.next( );
Payment credit2 =
user_input.next( );
```

You cannot assign a string value to a different class
Correct usage would be something like below

```
Payment cash1 = new Payment();
Payment cash2 = new Payment();
Payment credit1 = new Payment();
Payment credit2 = new Payment();

cash1.setPayment(new Double(user_input.next( )));
cash2.setPayment(new Double(user_input.next( )));
credit1.setPayment(new Double(user_input.next( )));
credit2.setPayment(new Double(user_input.next( )));
```

Also your code has a warning "Resource leak: 'user_input' is never closed"
You need to work this one out.

My suggestion you need to study Java programming language more before you start putting questions to correct your code. Your are missing basic points which are very important.

Comment: A payment expects a primitive *double*.

Comment: Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004370/what-is-the-difference-between-new-doublesomestring-and-double-parsedoublesom) as well...

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm in an intro to OOP class and we only recently began talking about security, hence the resource leak. Need to close that Scanner! Also, what do you use to compile and execute? I'm compiling fine but it's not running in CMD. I'm using TextPad and Java JDK 1.8.0_60.

Comment: in that case go over the suggestions made by me and ChiefTwoPencils. He has suggested to go over this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004370/what-is-the-difference-between-new-doublesomestring-and-double-parsedoublesom which is a nice explanation on Double primitive and Wrapper class usage